# Arranging words within a given string alphabetically

Tags: java

i'm just trying to write a code for arranging the words within  a string alphabetically..
But whenever i am running this it' entering in an infinite loop.. i cant figure out what is exactly happening..can  anybody help me out plzzz.. below i've attached my code.

```
public class AscendString {
    String s=new String();

    public AscendString(String x)
    {
        s=x.trim();
    }

    public int NoWords()
    {
        int i=0;
        String s1=new String();
        s1=s;
        while(s1.length() > 0)
        {   i++;
            int j=s1.indexOf(' ');
            if(j>0)
            {
                s1.substring(j+1);
                s1=s1.trim();
            }
            else
            s1="";
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void Ascend()
    {
        String str[]=new String[NoWords()];
        String s1=new String();
        s1=s;
        int i=0;
        while(s1.length() > 0)
        {
            int j=s1.indexOf(' ');
            if(j>0)
            {
                str[i]=s1.substring(0,j) ;
                s1=s1.substring(j+1);
                s1=s1.trim();
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                str[i]=s1;
                s1="";
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j < str.length-1;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k < str.length-1-j;k++)
            if(str[k].length() > str[k+1].length())
            {String temp=str[k];
                str[k]=str[k+1];
                str[k+1]=temp;
            }
        }
        String str1="";
        for(int n=0;n < str.length;n++)
        str1=str1+str[n] +" " ;
        System.out.println("The String in Alphabetic Order is: "+str1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        AscendString exmpl=new AscendString("I Love Java Programming");
        exmpl.Ascend();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you don't understand what your program is doing, the first thing you should try is stepping through your code in a debugger.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you making this hard?

```
String exmpl=new String("I Love Java Programming");  
String[] parts = exmpl.split("\\s+");   
Arrays.sort(parts);  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
for(String s:parts){  
   sb.append(s);  
   sb.append(" ");  
}  

String sorted = sb.toString.trim();
```

Comment: sir i am actually new to java..infact i am just a beginner. i was just taught the basic string operations & datatypes,control structures and i was given this assignment by my teacher.. i don't know the stringbuffer & the other things dat u coded here...bt seems to be very interesting to me & much short & compact dan what i did.. would  u explain ur steps plzzz...i want to learn it.

Comment: Split the sentence to words. Sort the words.Use stringbuilder to append sorted words and create the sorted string.Just look the javadoc

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
s1 = s1.substring(j+1);
```

`substring` return the sub-string, not changing the string., so this loop:

```
    while(s1.length() > 0)
    {   i++;
        int j=s1.indexOf(' ');
        if(j>0)
        {
            s1.substring(j+1);
            s1=s1.trim();
        }
        else
        s1="";
    }
```

Goes forever.

Comment: thankyou sir,i just missed it in my coding,i corrected it and it gave me my expected result..

Answer (score 0):

1. There is never any reason to call `new String(...)`.
2. Should punctuation matter?
3. What about repeated words?
4. Do you want strings to sort caring about case? What do you expect from "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama."?  "A Panama. a a canal man, plan,"

Adapting Cratylus' answer, you might change the regex to `\\W+`. You'd be splitting on runs of non-word-constituents.  And then, learn about `Collator` and `CollationKey`. You probably want case-insensitive searches.  Or, lower-case the string on the way in.

Comment: answering ur question no 4 i want exactly that you said.